# Is there a consolidated list of HTML attributes and classes that affect user agent password management?

Tags: passwords, html

I'm looking for a list of HTML Classes and other identifiers that cause a user agent, or user agent surrogate to invoke custom password handling features.

E.g.

- Secure Password auto-generation (iOS, Firefox, Chrome, etc)
- Proper identification of Name and Password fields (intentionally excluding temporary MFA results from being stored, overwriting the password)
- The ability to opt out of the above if the password requirements don't match the autogenerated ones (custom auth handlers rejecting hyphens in iOS suggestions)
- Excluding security question and answer responses from being stored

Comment: I think you are confusing 2 things: what clients look for and what the server sends. Is it not enough that the field is `<input type="password">`?

Comment: @schroeder Here is one example, I've seen others, but now I'm needing to aggregate the information https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

Comment: Ok, but this is looking more like an HTML problem than a security problem.

Comment: Also, your question doesn't seem to make much sense. HTML classes that invoke features?

Comment: in addition to the ones mentioned in your link you can set autocomplete="off" to tell the browser not to autofill.  (browser support for these tags does vary...)  The storage of passwords and collection of terms for autofill in general is up to the browser...  (storing passwords in the browser is not a great idea... anyone who can gain remote access to the user account will be able to use your accounts.  ex: log in to amazon and ship something to an address they pickup from)